How can I switch my SSD dual booted Windows-Ubuntu computer to a larger one without having to re-install. System as 256GB SSD and 1TB HDD
I have a dual-boot laptop with a 1TB HDD and a 256GB SSD. Both Windows and Linux are currently installed on the SSD.
The 1TB HDD is used to store large miscellaneous data and also contains the home partition of my Ubuntu installation.
I want to move both my OS installations to a larger SSD and boot from there. Could someone guide me on the steps to achieve this?
I’ve attached screenshots of the partition table from Gnome Disks for reference. If any additional information is needed, let me know.
Partial output of sudo fdisk -l(with all the Disk /dev/loopX removed) :-

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-256G-1101          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 68D8AE81-B2BA-45A1-94B2-34A049752456

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 341147647 340580352 162.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 341147648 341966847    819200   400M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p6 341966848 350158847   8192000   3.9G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p7 350158848 498069004 147910157  70.5G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1BA2F6A7-1935-4E98-BAB1-C3FC4D688EAD

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2       32768 1351952383 1351919616 644.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1351952384 1364240383   12288000   5.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1364242432 1773842431  409600000 195.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1773842432 1953525134  179682703  85.7G Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.




256GB SSD:-

1TB HDD:-


This question is similar to: How to clone entire hard-disk into new one?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have successfully used free Macrium Reflect on wnidows to do this dual boot copy. It allows resizing the partitions in the copy, so better than just a clone.
